# Convert .sh file to .bat file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I need to get a .sh file to work on windows environment, so I want to convert it **manually** to a .bat file, but the problem that I don't know the right syntax to do that, please can you help me, here's the .sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Needed by labeler.
export CLASSPATH=lthlabeler.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:utilities.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:trove.jar

# Needed for parser.
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:lthparser.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:trove.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:proj2NonProj.jar
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:nonProj2Proj.jar

MEMORY=1800M

MAIN_CLASS=se.lth.cs.nlp.labeler3.FrameNetLabeler

java -Xmx$MEMORY $MAIN_CLASS $*
```

Comment: I am assuming you expect us to translate that for you? Sorry mate, but that's not what we do here. [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/140505).

Comment: Can you lead me to a resource that can help?

Comment: No. [Stack Overflow is not a link farm or search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/140505) either. The question doesn't belong here.

Comment: Despite this sort of questions not really belonging here, one can treat them similar to homework questions and just nudge the asker in the right direction. Funnily enough the work involved in converting this snippet is actually less than posting the question on SO in the first place. Ah well.

Answer (score 9):

1. `export` is `set` in a batch file. See `help set`.
2. `FOO=BAR` is `set` too.
3. `$FOO` becomes `%FOO%`.
4. The colon for separating path entries is a semicolon on Windows.
5. `$*` becomes `%*`.
6. Comments are done with `REM` instead of `#`.

You should be able to figure it out fairly easily, now.

Comment: Note: I didn't recommend `::` on purpose for comments. (a) it's an artifact of the parser, (b) it's nowhere officially documented, [(c) it has lead to problems in the past already, making it a poor choice for batch files that should have a certain level of robustness](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php).